# how to give effect like youTube has on mouse movement,

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove

How to apply event of mousemove, so we can get effect like vlc player has for seekbar, or Youtube has for VideoTitle.

i.e : On mouse movement show title, if mouse not moved then hide title

**Why need** : I am developing website something like video library, there is one seekbar which I want to disable when mouse is not moved till someminute, and if mouse move then make it visible.

**What I Did :**

```
       document.body.onmousedown = function() {
            $(".myPrivateSeek").hide();
        };
        document.body.onmouseup = function() {
            $(".myPrivateSeek").show();
        };
```

althought its wroking,Unfortunately its not so much helpfull,

Comment: you can use `mousemove` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like it so that on mouse movement your element appears then after a specified time of no movement it automatically disappears you could implement the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeoutId;
    //Replace document.body with the element you wish the mouse movement to be recognised within.
    $(document.body).on('mousemove', function () {
        //Checks if an existing timeout function exists, if so remove it.
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        $(".myPrivateSeek").show();
        //Set a callback for how long to wait after the mouse has stopped moving to hide your element.
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $(".myPrivateSeek").hide();
        }, 1000); //The time in milliseconds to wait.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `mousemove` event.

Below is a working code for that , you can play with it [here in JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C37Un/) and modify as you want.

**HTML**

```
<div id="item">
    <p>This is my item</p>
    <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#item {
        position: relative;

        background: #CCC;
    }

    #item .tooltip {
        position: fixed;
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #06F;
        z-index: 10;
        display: none;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#item").on('mousemove', function(e) { 

            $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 10).css('top', e.pageY + 10).css('display', 'block');

        });

        $("#item").mouseout(function() { 
            $('.tooltip').css('display', 'none');
        });

    });
```